# How I can generate a voxel mesh from a set of points with x, y, and z coordinates in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, pixel, mesh, voxel

I have an excel file containing the coordinates of nodes from a simulation in Abaqus. Now I want to reconstruct a voxel mesh or a pixel mesh in 2D from these points in Matlab or in Python. One method I read was to use a zero matrix with the desired resolution and populate it but I do not really know how to implement this.

this is a link showing the structure of my excel file.

[image]

The result should be pixel based like this image:

[image]

Comment: What kind of data do you want to store in it? Do you have any information assigned to each node? And what exactly do you mean by "2D voxel mesh"?

Comment: 2D pixel mesh since my data is just x and y coordinates and 3D voxel-based model if there was a z coordinate as well. I need to recreate a binary model from these coordinates, but for this stage, if I could plot these coordinates as a pixel-based image it would be sufficent.

Comment: So you want to generate a 2D grid of 0s, then for each point in a list and mark closest node in grid as 1. Then display it as an image. Right?

Comment: Yes. that is what I hope for to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate coordinates of nodes of mesh. Also use [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) for calculating pair-wise distances of two sets of points (e.g. mesh nodes and points).

```
% generate some random points
n = 20;
mind = -10;
maxd = 30;
P = rand(n, 2) * (maxd - mind) + mind;

% generate grid
d = 0.25; % distance between two pixels in your metric
X = mind:d:maxd;
Y = X;
[XX, YY] = meshgrid(X, Y);

% find closest grid cell to each point
[~, imind] = pdist2([XX(:), YY(:)], P, 'seuclidean' ,'Smallest',1);

% generate equivalent image
I = false(length(Y), length(X));
I(imind) = true;

% display results
subplot 121, scatter(P(:, 1), P(:, 2)); 
xlim([mind maxd]); ylim([mind maxd]); title('Points')
subplot 122, imagesc('XDATA', X, 'YDATA', Y, 'CDATA', I); 
xlim([mind maxd]); ylim([mind maxd]); title('Equivalent Pixels')
```

[image]

However, you need to decide about a few constants, e.g. `minx`, `maxx`, `miny`, `maxy` and `d`. Updating this to support 3D is trivial. Both `meshgrid` and `pdist2` support 3D. Except the result will also be a 3D matrix. You can use `implay` or `slice` to show such images.